# Intel Rapid Storage RAID10 volume fails after GPU installation

Tags: hard-drive, raid, sata, gpu

So, after I successfully installed a GPU in my server and started the server again, the RAID volume failed to initialize.

I have 4 HDD's (2TB each, same model) in RAID10 and this RAID has been working without issues for at least 3 years straight. When I boot, this is what I see inside the Rapid storage manager:

[image]

So it seems it can still see all drives, but two of the drives dropped out of the array for some reason.

After digging a bit deeper, I realized that the serial number on the missing HDD's seems to have dropped the "W" at the start of the Serial number:
[image]

Could it be, that installing the GPU changed the internal ports of the HDD's? I never unplugged any HDD during the process and they are all still connected to the same SATA plug on the motherboard.

I have to fix this as fast as possible, anyone of you know a solution of how I can "remap" those HDD's to be inside the array (without loosing any data)?

Comment: Some ports may be dependant on having enough PCIe lanes free, but I've only really seen motherboards that state certain SATA ports being disabled when an m.2 SSD was installed. I wouldn't really expect it when plugging in  graphics card.

Comment: @Mokubai I have an ASUS Z87M Plus motherboard

Comment: Out of curiosity, do your drives work if you unplug your GPU?

Comment: Which slot did you plug the graphics card into? Do you have anything plugged in to the PCIe x1 slots?